# How to write a Report query based on number of days in a month?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a query to generate automated report. This report is to run for last month's transactions it should run on 1st of every month. I have job to run this report to run 1st of every month. But how can I make this query to choose no of days in a month? (some months will have 30 and some will have 31 and in feb no of days changes based on leap year).
Here one more requirement is I only have to pass one parameter in the query. below is example of query that I have now

```
select id,name,address,trans_dt from tab1 where trans_dt between to_date('&1','MM-DD-YYYY')-30 AND to_date('&1','MM-DD-YYYY');
```

The above query is generating last 30 days transactions,  but it will be wrong if no days for month is 31 or 28. I am using oracle 11r2 as database. Please help in writing this.

Comment: You can use last_day function to get the last day of a particular month.  Select * from example_table where start_date is between to_date ('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and last_day (your date) 
Writing from a mobile device so excuse me for not being able to get into detail

Comment: thats will not satisfy my criteria because  we want run this at 1st of each month, so if I use this function it will get records from 1st  Jan to 28th feb which is 2 months worth of data. Its not one time query its runs every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution but forget to reply here. Here is my solution

```
select id,name,address,trans_dt from tab1 where trans_dt between trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'MM') and trunc(sysdate,'MM');
```

above will give you report from 1st day of month to last day of month from calender.

Answer (score 0):

mySQL

```
SELECT 
   id,
   NAME,
   address,
   trans_dt 
FROM
   tab1 
WHERE 
   MONTH(trans_dt) = 02 /* Param for month passed in */
AND 
   YEAR(trans_dt) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Oracle

```
SELECT 
   id,
   NAME,
   address,
   trans_dt 
FROM
   tab1 
WHERE 
   to_char( dt_column, 'mm' ) = 02 /* Param for month passed in */
AND 
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE trans_dt) = trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')
```

Maybe this can work?  I only really know mySQL

Comment: thanks for your input but seems its not same in oracle

Comment: a quick search showed:  to_char( dt_column, 'mm' ) -- returns 01..12 so maybe WHERE to_char( trans_dt, 'mm' )

Comment: AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE trans_dt) = trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
      ,name
      ,address
      ,trans_dt from tab1 
  where trans_dt between to_date(p_dt,'yyyy-mmm-dd') and add_months(to_date(p_dt,'yyyy-mmm-dd'))
```